# moment.calendar() is giving the result in reverse order

Tags: momentjs

I am using moment(2.17.1) in my react-native app.By writing moment.calendar() I am getting the current time as  **7:30pm Today** while the expected result is  **Today at 7:30 PM**(according to documentation).I am not able to understand why I am getting the response in the different format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution 1 : update locale

```
moment.updateLocale('en', {
    calendar : {
        sameDay : 'LT [Today]'
    },
})

let date1 = moment().calendar();
console.log(date1);                                 // 4:25 PM Today
```

solution 2 : use format `instead` of `calendar`

```
let date1 = moment().calendar();
console.log(date1);                                 // Today at 4:25 PM

let date2 = moment().format('hh:mma [Today]');
console.log(date2);                                 // 04:25pm Today

let date3 = moment().format('HH:mm A [Today]');
console.log(date3);                                 // 16:25 PM Today
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.But in my system for console.log(date1) it is showing 4:25pm Today.Can you tell me how to get the date in correct format and what is the reason it is showing in different format?

Comment: @DhruvilShah Hi. you can use `format()` function and dos'nt use `calendar()` function. try this `moment().format('hh:mma')`

Comment: @DhruvilShah Hi. I update answer. please check solutions